# Windicss used daisyui checkbox and toggle not working?

Tags: tailwind-css, daisyui, windicss

**windi.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig, transform } from 'windicss/helpers'
import type { Plugin } from 'windicss/types/interfaces'

// plugins
import TypographyPlugin from 'windicss/plugin/typography'
import AspectRatioPlugin from 'windicss/plugin/aspect-ratio'
import FiltersPlugin from 'windicss/plugin/filters'
  plugins: [
    FiltersPlugin as Plugin,
    TypographyPlugin as Plugin,
    AspectRatioPlugin as Plugin,
    transform('daisyui') // daisyui register as plugin
  ] as Plugin[],
})
```

When I click on checkbox or toggle It's not active checked
How to fixed it. Thank you!

[image]